# How i increase the width of column when we create the csv file using FileWriter in java

Tags: excel, file, csv, filewriter

I want to create the Csv file using FileWriter.

After the Csv file Generate the column width Preferred the header Name width and create the column Width according to this so my Data not Display the proper in Csv file so i want to increase the Width of column i used filewriter to Generate the Csv File i try many solution but it does not work.

Show below the generate Csv file and code which I have used.

[image]

i have used used Below code.

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: In a CSV file columns don't have a "width". You will need to create a _real_ Excel file (e.g. using POI) to control the width

Comment: can we not increase the width of column in FileWriter is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file cannot hold the column width because it has no styling at all and no capacity to hold any.

You can try exporting to a different file type such as XML or alternately set the values in the header row to equal the same as the maximum character count for each column

For example from your data:
`"Name"` becomes `"Name             "`

But this will only work if the application used to read the file sets the width equal to the header row values by default.

Comment: i want to write the csv file not read this solution not work for me .

Comment: @YashPathak Please understand a CSV stands for Comma Separated Values. The only content in a CSV file (that is written correctly) will be commas and values. There are no other details in this file type. Use an excel XML as this is the simplest file that will give you the formatting you desire. If you would like and example of excel XML let me know.

Answer (score 0):

i have Create CSV file using Poi its work For me and they increase the Column Width according to Data Display in Column  i used the 
**sheet.autoSizeColumn(column index);** this function increase the column width according to its Column Data.